# How do I make one of a stub's method call the real method in ASMock?

Tags: apache-flex, asmock

In flex I want to do something similar to the following

```
var audioPlayerMock:AudioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mockRepository.createStub(mockRepository.createStub(AudioPlayer));
SetupResult.forCall(audioPlayerMock.play).(CALL_ACTUAL_PLAY_METHOD(WITH_ARGUMENT));
```

AudioPlayer has a lot of methods that I want stubbed, (so I use `mockRepository.creatStub()`). But there is one method, `play()`, that I want to call the actual actual method (`super.play(argument)` if my thinking is right). I'm not sure how to do this?

I know I can use `createDynamic(AudioPlayer)` then stub out every other method, but that is a bit tedious.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IMethodOptions.callOriginalMethod()` to call the actual implementation on a stubbed class:

```
SetupResult.forCall(authatoPlayerMock.play(null))
    .ignoreArguments()
    .callOriginalMethod();
```